# Does Qt5 accept Numpy float64?

Tags: c++, qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm making a `QTableView` based on a `QStandardItemModel`. I add data in the following fashion:

```
def addTableXYData(self,row):
    label = 'Point '+str(row)
    data = [label, self.x[row-1], self.y[row-1]]
    for index, item in enumerate(data):
        self.tableModel.setData(self.tableModel.index(row-1,index), item)
    self.tableModel.layoutChanged.emit()
```

The strings for the label show up fine in the table, however it doesn't show the numbers. The numbers come from clicking points on a Matplotlib Qt Canvas, and are naturally `numpy.float64` dtypes.

Is Qt5 capable of handling `numpy.float64` datatypes? Or must I change it in to something else? I assume it may have something to do with PyQt5 using bindings to the C++ language, and maybe that can't handle it?

I've tried reading the docs on `QVariant` but it doesn't seem to tell me that I can't use floats.

**Edit** Instead of down-voting me without saying anything how about laying some wisdom on me and helping me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that PyQt5 does not possess the capability of sending numpy datatype classes to Qt5. It does native python classes like `int()`, `float()` etc. but not `numpy.int32()` etc. I assumed that would have been built-in functionality but, there ya go. The more you know.